# App-Bar usage with other menus in Metro UI CSS

Tags: microsoft-metro, metro-ui-css

In Metro UI CSS, can I use other menus (Horizontal, Vertical, M-Menu, etc.) in an app-bar besides app-bar-menu?

The documentation does not give examples of mixing them, and when I try they are not behaving correctly:

In the app-bar-menu the menus stack in one column in mobile, but not when using the other menus.

Comment: What do you mean by "not behaving correctly."? Please describe the expected behavior and what you are experiencing - if you are getting any errors, also include the error message(s) - this is more helpful for the community to understand what might be to problem.

Comment: In app-bar-menu the menus stacks in one column in mobile but not when using the other menus.

Comment: I added the explanation, which you added in comments, to your answer.